# How to let user set an image file to private or public in Firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase, angular5, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I'm building a web app with Firebase and Angular 6. 
This web application has image upload feature which can be used by its users.

Uploaded image file will go to firebase's storage associated with user's id. All images will be displayed in main page by default.

How can I let user choose to set their images private or public? 
I understand this has to do with security rules at Firebase but I wonder how I can associate this with individual user's files?

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [object (custom) metadata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata) to store the users' decisions about each file, and checking those decisions in security rules using [resource evaluation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/secure-files#resource_evaluation).

Comment: Thanks for your response! is there any example github project or source code for this? It's very confusing...

Comment: Not that I know of.